# Missing Database Table Baking an App with CakePHP using Aliases?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a `users` table with a reference to `tenant_id` and `manager_id` (these are my aliases for the `users` model).  When I try to bake the model, I get the following error:

`Error: Missing database table 'tenants' for model 'Tenant'`

I thought bake would allow me to tell it what my aliases are.  Am I doing something wrong, or do I just have to manually create my models and forego baking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic of Cake is, I think, being clever and saying, "According to CakePHP convention, `tenant_id` points to `Tenant.id` and `manager_id` points to `Manager.id`, but I can't find those tables."

I would be inclined to code the model myself - I rarely use bake except when I'm laying down a project and things aren't too complex.

It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve here. Does `tenant_id` mirror `User.id`? If you are trying to do what I think you are, then you'll need to create three Models - **User**, **Tenant** and **Manager** and code something like:

(models/tenant.php)

```
class Tenant extends AppModel {
   var $useTable = 'users'; // This model uses the 'users' database table.
}
```

Comment: In my `users` table I have `tenant_id` and `manager_id` (but no `user_id`).  Rather than having separate `tenants` and `managers` tables I wanted to use cake's aliasing capability to keep it all in one table.  I don't mind building the models myself, I just wanted to use bake to save some time.  Perhaps if I create the models manually I can still use bake to create the controllers and views.

Comment: It'll only take five minutes to write the models. You should still be able to bake the controller and views. I usually do copy, cut & paste followed by search & replace.

Comment: Your suggestion worked like a charm.  After creating the model, I was able to bake it and have cakephp automagically make all the associations.  Thanks!